# Planet SkySat - Differences between image strips

Tags: remote-sensing, image-classification, planet, skysat

I'm trying to understand why i'm seeing variations in the analytic (surface reflectance) imagery brightness values in Planet SkySat imagery between image strips that were collected around the same time.

I'm aware of the differences between analytic and visual products (i.e. this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178251/whats-the-difference-between-the-analytic-and-visual-images-available-through-t)), but i'm hoping someone can shed some light on why the analytic product contains these differences. Surely if it is being used for scientific analysis, the brightness values should be comparable between image strips? Example below (i've mosaicked these images into one):
[image]

Am I missing a processing step here? The visual product seems to show similar differences. My use case is image classification, so ideally I need these mosaics to contain comparable brightness values across image strips to allow me to apply a classification model consistently across the whole area.

Comment: It generally seems like the raw image strips from SkySat (and Doves) are not well inter-calibrated. This is generally the standard, when images are not acquired exactly at the same time, so nothing out of the ordinary here.

Comment: Thanks @MikkelLydholmRasmussen, interesting. So I guess another step of manual processing is required to match these up? Would have expected them to line up better as it will potentially impact image classification across a large area, especially when doing repeat analysis over a time series.

Comment: In general, expecting imagery from acquired at different angles to line up spectrally is quite optimistic. The 'analytic product' is mostly related to it containing the full bit-depth, in contrast to the mosaic product that is also available, where colour balancing (and bit-reduction) has taken place.